# Using Regular Expression Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am looking to use a regular expression to capture the last value in a string. I have copied an example of the data I am looking to parse. I am using oracle syntax.

Example Data:

```
||CULTURE|D0799|D0799HTT|
||CULTURE|D0799|D0799HTT||
```

I am looking to strip out the last value before the last set of pipes:

```
D0799HQTT 
D0799HQTT
```

I am able to create a regexp_substr that returns the CULTURE:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(c.field_name, '|[^|]+|')
```

but I have not been able to figure out how to start at the end look for either one or two pipes, and return the values I'm looking for. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Have You tried splitting the string and picking up last not empty element?

Comment: Like this: `array = str.split('|'); int i = array.length; while(array[i].isEmpty()){ i--; } array[i] = yourLastValue;` Hope its clear what I wrote. ;)

Comment: @KamilW. How does that answer the question (splitting the string in Oracle using regexes)?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Thank You for good question. What I thought is that maybe The Author will use it like in this example: http://sqltutorials.blogspot.com/2007/09/sql-function-split.html  It was just a quick response. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following Regex...

```
(?<=\|)[\w\d]*?(?=\|*$)
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Are you sure that Oracle supports lookahead?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
select rtrim(regexp_substr('||CULTURE|D0799|D0799HTT||', 
                     '[[:alnum:]]+\|+$'), '|')
from dual;
```

Or like this:

```
select regexp_replace('||CULTURE|D0799|D0799HTT||', 
                     '(^|.*\|)([[:alnum:]]+)\|+$', '\2')
from dual;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/20673)

Comment: Maybe this is easier for "||CULTURE SUBS|INTERNATIONAL TESTING S.A.|ISLAND TEST_PEACE|" I want to return "ISLAND TEST_PEACE". Do you have any suggestions on how to take into consideration spaces and special characters?

Comment: Instead of `[[:alnum:]]` use your own class, i.e. `[a-zA-Z0-9 _]`

Comment: ah very good! thank you very much, you helped learn more about regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably best to pull out all characters that are not pipes, rather than to assume that they will fit into a specific character set:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_substr('||CULTURE SUBS|INTERNATIONAL TESTING S.A.|ISLAND TEST_PEACE|', '[^|]+\|+$'), '\|', '') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  REPLACE
        (
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '\w+\W{0,}$')
        ,   '|'
        ) AS result
FROM
(
        SELECT  '||CULTURE|D0799|D0799HTT|'  AS str FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT  '||CULTURE|D0799|D0799HTT||' AS str FROM DUAL
)
;
```